# Delete entries from firebase realtime database for c#

Tags: c#, firebase

i'm trying to delete child entries from firebase realtime database for c# aplication. i'm unable to find any suitable method in firebase documentation. please help. PS: i'm new to firebase

Comment: please write the code what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you 2 ways to delete data from the FireBaseStorage database, if you had something else like deleting from FireBaseReatimeDatabase, then write to me, so here are 2 of these methods:
(C# I use the FireSharp and FireBase libraries)

```
using FireSharp.Config;
using FireSharp.Interfaces;
using FireSharp;
using FirebaseSharp;
using Firebase.Storage;
using FireSharp.EventStreaming;
using FireSharp.Exceptions;
using FireSharp.Response;
using Firebase;
using FirebaseSharp.Portable.Interfaces;




        public void DeleteFile(String stream)
        {
            //Delete file in FireBaseStorage 2 answer
            FirebaseStorage storage = new FirebaseStorage("********.appspot.com");
            var starsRef = storage.Child(stream);
            starsRef.DeleteAsync();
            //or
            var task = new FirebaseStorage("*******.appspot.com")
                .Child(stream)
                .DeleteAsync();
        }
```

stream is the path to the file

Answer (score -1):

What about RemoveValueAsync? Here:

[DatabaseReference.RemoveValueAsync](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/database-reference#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_database_reference_1ad77e1c00f6edbe8dc23ffd9a01174631)

It would be like

```
DatabaseReference rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
DatabaseReference childToRemove = rootReference.Child("your child path");

childToRemove.RemoveValueSync().ContinueWith(
            (task) =>
            {
                if (task.IsCanceled || task.IsFaulted) Debug.Log("Fail");
                else if (task.IsCompleted) Debug.Log("Success");
            });
```